# Python threading arguments passing

Tags: python, thread-safety, python-multithreading

I would like to understand the difference between the ways we can pass arguments to threads and if this has any effect on thread safety.

I am using python 3.7.3 and both instances of the code runs fine for me.

Example 1:
`thread = threading.Thread(target=MultiHandler().handle, args=(argument))`

Example 2:
`thread = threading.Thread(target=MultiHandler().handle(argument))`

Comment: `MultiHandler().handle` is a function that the thread will call. `MultiHandler().handle(argument)` is the *return value* of the function *after* it has been called, before the thread has even started. They are entirely different things.

Comment: Also, `args` is expected to be a tuple; you need `args=(argument,)`, not `args=(argument)` (which is equivalent to `args=argument`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`target` should be the callable object to be invoked, not the result of the function call, 
unless your 2nd sample function returns another callable (`target=MultiHandler().handle(argument)` returns ---> `callable`).

Answer (score 0):

Python allows both args and kwargs in threading as arguments. And that can be used to make decisions inside a function. 
And it's the callable function where thread safety applies not on the arguments.